# How do I run Dartium in a different process from an existing Chromium instance?

Tags: dart, chromium, dartium

For example, if I already have a `chromium` running, and I try to run [Dartium](https://webdev.dartlang.org/tools/dartium) (a special developer-only version of Chrome with the Dart VM embedded), it opens a new tap or window in my existing `chromium` instance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`--user-data-dir`](https://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory) Chromium flag to isolate Dartium and force it to run in a new process/window. For example:

```
$ chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/dartium
```

The new [DartDevCompiler](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/tree/master/pkg/dev_compiler) will allow you to just simply use a major browser, like Chrome, for development, instead of relying on Dartium - with a fast edit-refresh cycle that compiles `.dart` to idiomatic ES6 `.js`.